# What is return oriented programming?

Tags: security

What is return oriented programming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Science Daily](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2009/08/090810161902.htm):

> In 2007, [Hovav] Shacham first described
>   return-oriented programming, which is
>   a powerful systems security exploit
>   that generates malicious behavior by
>   combining short snippets of benign
>   code already present in the system.

Hovav Shacham's paper on the topic [Return-Oriented Programming: Exploits Without Code Injection](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~hovav/talks/blackhat08.html).

Answer (score 4):

It's a way to perform security exploits without code injection, see [here](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~hovav/talks/blackhat08.html) .